# Numbers appear all over mesh

Tags: mesh

Can anyone please tell me what all these numbers are, or better yet how to get rid of them? They appear when I "select" anything: https://gyazo.com/99a42904702e4ed92f8295cad67e3e18

I cannot seem to get rid of them, no matter what I click.  I suspect I turned them on with an unknown keyboard combination.  I just want to know how to get rid of them!  I cannot build with numbers obscuring the mesh!

Answer (score 2):

It was *Edge Length* checked just below the *Normals*, in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> *Recalculate Normals* dialog.

Comment: Please say which version of Blender you're using if it's not visible on the image. In version 2.8 and above the Measurement overlays are accessed via the Overlay dropdown menu in Edit mode, **not** via CTRL +N which brings up the new file menu! :^)